# How to send JSON data correctly using Axios to a rails server, to match the required rails params hash correctly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, vue.js, axios

I am making a GET request to a rails server, and the parameter should look like:

```
{"where"=>{"producer_id"=>["7"]}
```

I am making the request from the frontend application which is in Vue, and using Axios for making the request. I am making the request like this:

```
const data = await this.axios.get('http://localhost:3000/data.json', {
  headers: {
    'X-User-Token': this.$store.getters.authToken,
    'X-User-Username': this.$store.getters.user.username
  },
  params: {
    where: {
      producer_id: data.producers
    }
  }
})
```

However, in the rails server output it shows that the params were sent like this:

```
{"where"=>"{\"producer_id\":[\"7\"]}"}
```

And I don't get the correct data back because of it.

How can I solve this? Why is the second level in `params` (the `where` object) being sent as a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that in this case the params have to be serialized https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/738

I used the `paramsSerializer` function as well to get over this

```js
const data = await this.axios.get('http://localhost:3000/data.json', {
  headers: {
    'X-User-Token': this.$store.getters.authToken,
    'X-User-Username': this.$store.getters.user.username
  },
  params: {
    where: {
      producer_id: data.producers
    }
  },
  paramsSerializer: function (params) {
    return jQuery.param(params)
  }
})
```

EDIT:

I am now using `qs` instead of jQuery:

```js
axios.defaults.paramsSerializer = (params) => {
  return qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'})
}
```